# Possible to specify a cache length or a forced refresh for a JavaScript file from the hosting server?

Tags: javascript, caching

We are producing a JavaScript library that will be included by web pages on other domains that we do not have direct control over.  Ideally, we'd like that file cached, but also have the ability to tell users' browsers (that have loaded the web page that includes our .js file) to clear its cache and reload that .js file should we need to push a bug fix or similar.  If an 'on demand' refresh isn't possible, than we'd like to set an appropriate time to live so that changes are picked up at a reasonably predictable interval.  Is this possible?

**EDIT**: While I'm fully aware of the tricks like adding a querystring to the .js source URL or changing the name of the .js file when the content changes, all of these as far as I can tell require updating the source of the page that includes the .js file  (and that page I don't control).  My desired solution requires no change to the HTML source of the including page after the initial 'here add this JavaScript include (or similar) to your page'

Comment: You can set this on your server, or you can append a querystring to the js file which will force the browser to load a new version, as long as the querystring changes `<script src="somefile.js?version=123"></script>` but since you don't have control of those sites, you need to do this on your server, or there is another way...

Comment: Elaborate on 'set this on your server' please.

Comment: What type of server are you using? Linux? Windows running IIS? ...

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't have control over the third-party website you can't append to the querystring which is a simple way to force update the script. You can control the length of time the script is cached for by the server, or to force the JS to update every time you want it to, you can do this

This is for the website owner "Here, include this in your page"

```
<script src="http://link/to/loadthisone.js"></script>
```

But loadthisone.js is only a small file. The server is told never to cache that file, or maybe for a few hours. It's small so that's not too offensive. This one loads the bigger JS library that you don't want site visitors to reload every single time.

**loadthisone.js**

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'http://link/to/the/real/js/file.js?version=123'; // the library and version
head.appendChild(script);
```

You would then update the version number in this script (manually or automatically) when you push a new version.

If you can't make any changes on the server, you can serve loadthisone.js using PHP and force no-cache that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can "fake" a new request by adding a querystring to an URL:

```
<script src="http://eternalsite.com/js/script.js?v=1"></script>
```

How and when this happens would have to be controlled by your script.

Comment: "that will be included by web pages on other domains that we do not have direct control over"

Comment: Yes, but one would assume that the script you're already including from your site would do this task.

Comment: @Diodeus can you elaborate on how we'd do this assuming the only control we have over the hosting webpage is 'here, add this code to your page'

Comment: You'd have to insert a a script pointing to your page. That script would then read all of the script tags on your page, then change the SRC based on some rules.